# Subscript out of range error - saveas method

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get Excel to "saveas" a workbook by using the following code:

```
Sub SaveWorkbook(my_FileName, sFolder)

Dim workbook_Name As String
Dim fName As String

fName = CStr(Range("B9").Value)
workbook_Name = "\" & fName & ".xls"

Workbooks(my_FileName).SaveAs fileName:=sFolder & workbook_Name

End Sub
```

`my_FileName` and `sFolder` are being passed by another function:

```
Sub ProduceDoc()

MsgBox "Please Select the File that Contains the Document"
my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*,*.xsl*,*.xm*")

sFolder = "C:\Users\" & InputBox("Please type your employee id") & "\Desktop\" & InputBox("What will you name your folder?")

Workbooks.Open (my_FileName)

SaveWorkbook (my_FileName)

End Sub
```

The subscript error is currently being thrown for the line:

```
Workbooks(my_FileName).SaveAs fileName:=sFolder & workbook_Name
```

and I can't figure out why. I'm assuming it's happening because I'm forgetting something simple.

What I've done so far to test:

Verified that `my_FileName` is successfully being passed to the function `SaveWorkbook()`, and it is. I was able to open the document specified in function `ProduceDoc()` and get `my_FileName` to print in a certain cell within `SaveWorkbook()`

That's all I have in the toolkit atm. Any thoughts?

Edit: I've now updated the line `Workbooks(my_FileName).SaveAs fileName:=sFolder & workbook_Name` to show new state, and also sFolder is being called in . It is still giving the same error.

Comment: remove the quotes

Comment: That and I do not see where you assign a value to `SFolder`

Comment: I've just edited the code to reflect the changes, the same error is being thrown. I've double and triple checked that `sFolder`, `my_FileName` and `workbook_Name` are producing the expected strings, and they are. Stuck.

Comment: What is in B9 ie `fName = CStr(Range("B9").Value)` there could be chars you are not allowed in a filename. Put this before the SaveAs `msgbox sFolder & workbook_Name` and see what it says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Everything was formatted correctly in all variables, except for these two lines:

```
workbook_Name = "\" & fName & ".xls"

Workbooks(my_FileName).SaveAs fileName:=sFolder & workbook_Name
```

Excel didn't like a few things here, so I tried to make it as basic as I could. I combined the concatenation of `sFolder` and `workbook_Name` into one variable, removed  `".xls"`, and added the `fileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal` argument into the SaveAs method.

What I think really fixed this is how I called the SaveAs method. Changed that to "ActiveWorkbook" rather than what is was previously.

```
workbook_Name = sFolder & "\" & fName

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=workbook_Name, fileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
```

It all behaves as expected now!

hope this helps anyone who runs into this in the future!